# Integrate JSON data with publishing process in gatsby-node.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I've created a function inside gatsby-node.js that creates links between users and locations and publishes them to the correct path based on the info from the markdown files.

Now, I have a local data.json with a survey data for every user that I need to integrate into this function.

I need to import data from the data.json and check - if the currently processed User page has a matching email address in data.json, then add the testimonials to the output data. I'm struggling to find a way of how to integrate this logic into the existing function.

Node.js

```
const path = require("path");
const { createFilePath } = require("gatsby-source-filesystem");
const data = require("src/data/data.json");

exports.createPages = ({ actions, graphql }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions;

    return graphql(`
        {
            allMarkdownRemark(limit: 1000) {
                edges {
                    node {
                        id
                        fields {
                            slug
                        }
                        frontmatter {
                            templateKey
                            title
                            location
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `).then(result => {
        if (result.errors) {
            result.errors.forEach(e => console.error(e.toString()));
            return Promise.reject(result.errors);
        }

        const edges = result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges;

        edges.forEach(edge => {
            const id = edge.node.id;
            const title = edge.node.frontmatter.title;
            const location = edge.node.frontmatter.location || null;
            createPage({
                path: edge.node.fields.slug,
                component: path.resolve(
                    `src/templates/${String(
                        edge.node.frontmatter.templateKey,
                    )}.js`,
                ),
                // query variables are passed in via the context
                context: {
                    id,
                    title,
                    location,
                },
            });
        });
    });
};

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
    const { createNodeField } = actions;

    if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
        const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode });
        createNodeField({
            name: `slug`,
            node,
            value,
        });
    }
};
```

JSON

```
[
  {
    "agreed": true,
    "email": "alex@test.com"
    "testimonials": [
      {
        "name": "Alex",
        "city": "Pedro",
        "state": "WA",
        "description": "Alex was very patient. He is one of the good guys!"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the email field in the graphql query, inside the frontmatter property from your markdown files. From there you can use `data.find(u => u.email == edge.node.frontmatter.social_id)` to find the right user, and pass the whole object in the comtext of createPage, or just the testimonials, your call.